# How do I import CSS just for some classes or ids?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say, I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="body">Body</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

And an external CSS file (`/styles.css`), which contains

```
#header{
    color:red;
}    
#footer{
    color:red;
}
```

Now with the help of javascript I can easily load the whole CSS, so as the text color of `#header` and `#footer` becomes red.

Using javascript, is it possible to load only styles which refer to `#header` and filter out any other styles in my stylesheet (styles for `#footer` in my case)?

Comment: Do you mean remove them for the sake of browser performance or server optimization? Either way there's going to be processing, difference is one can't be done.

Comment: @Bryan No, I just don't want this stylesheet to apply to anything except #header.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by directly modifying the CSS rules being applied to the current document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Important: Place this where it will be executed once all the CSS resources have been loaded (i.e, beginning or the end of the body tag)

    // The will be an array of all the selectors to keep CSS rules for
    ruleList = ["#header"];
    var docRulesEntry = document.all ? 'rules' : 'cssRules';

    // Loop through loaded stylesheets
    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        if(document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry] !== null && document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry] !== undefined)
        {
            // Loop through stylesheet rules
            for(var o = 0; o < document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry].length; o++)
            {
                if(document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o] !== null && document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o] !== undefined)
                {
                    // Check if selector exists in our ruleList array
                    if(ruleList.indexOf(document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o].selectorText) == -1
                        && document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o].style !== undefined && document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o].style !== null)
                    {
                        // Selector was not found, remove CSS rules
                        document.styleSheets[i][docRulesEntry][o].style.cssText = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle demo (tested on Chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/ud5svdky/1/

Comment: Ohwait... I have no idea what's doing yet, but it appears to work :D

Comment: @nicael Glad to hear that. CSS rule modifications are a bit complicated in general.

Comment: I gonna test in real life :)

Comment: Nice! Is there any risk of FOUC issues, though? Can I be sure that the browser won't apply the original stylesheet first, then only re-display the page after I modify it?

Comment: @Kos It depends on where it's placed. When at the beginning of the body element or end of the head element, there shouldn't be issues with synchronously loaded CSS documents (because the DOM has yet to be rendered). I would see issues with async loading however.